# Designing an api - should we include 4xx responses or not in open api specification?

Tags: swagger, openapi

While designing a GET endpoint I am confused ...
Have designed Open API spec 3.0 for successful response ( 200 )  , invalid request ( missing mandatory stuff ) ( 400 )

Now I am confused about things like : 401 ( Unauthorized ) , 405 ( Method not allowed ) , 415 ( Unsupported Media type )

This API will need an api key to be provided in header and if not provided by user or an invalid api key is provided then they should get a 401
So I think I should be specifying 401 in my response spec .
However when I look at swagger's Pet store ( https://editor.swagger.io/ ) they are not having this response code anywhere ... ?

My API spec ONLY supports GET with Content-type : application/json so I am thinking we dont need 405 ( DELETE / POST / PUT etc ) .
Similarly if consumer sends application/xml or anything other than application/json we are not supporting it so this is why we should not be explicitly defining 415 in the spec ?

A bit confused which is why am looking into some inputs.
Was referring to some pages [here](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev-guides/api-design/api-best-practices-response-handling/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However when I look at swagger's Pet store they are not having this response code anywhere ... ?

The Pet Store is really just an example that one can use as a starting point or when you want to feed a tool with a sample spec. It is not meant to be normative. If you look through the sample code, you will even find paths which are RPC style ([e.g. here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-petstore/blob/master/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml#L282)) and other things that are not exactly RESTful.

> why we should not be explicitly defining 415 in the spec ?

I think the blogposts that you found are helpful and do not contradict each other. Both of them rightfully recommend you to use the standard http response codes and provide a helpful error body. Some people omit response codes that they think are self-explanatory. But IMO, adding these few lines is totally worth it.  If you add them diligently, then you get a key aspect of openapi right: The purpose of openapi is clarity and predictability of the capabilities and behaviour of your API.

So in summary: **Yes**, think about the responses that you are going to need, and **do include these response codes** in your api spec.

Comment: thank you  ! , so I have an api key based authentication , so will include 401 , 405 too since my api only supports GET so need 405 if consumer calls any other VERB , 415 too in case consumer sends content-type other than application/json and also finally 500 for any unknown issues . This does raise a question though , I have hardly seen any spec which has all of these error codes specified in the spec , ( I know it would be situational ) but 500 should always be present for unexpected scenarios ?

Comment: For the sake of completeness, clearly yes. However, there is not much added value in specifying the 500 case. Do not specify any specific error message or custom response body – the server-side failure state might prevent these from being issued.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a good idea to document the Response Codes the API might return, it is indeed [supported](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/) (but optional) by OpenAPI.
The consumers might find useful to know `401` Unauthorized means the JWT token is not supplied or it is expired, or `400` means the payload is incorrect (i.e. missing a specific attribute).

Check this [example](https://api.tweesky.com/apidocs/) if you would like to see how Response Codes are documented and displayed by Swagger UI.